# How to select 1 userID, and not every single one

Tags: mysql, database-design, php, greatest-n-per-group

Currently, this .php file assigns to each chore, every single User that exists in the database, I think this is because it repeats, how do I make it only pick 1 random UserID instead?

```php
<?php
session_start();
include 'conn.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['type']!="admin") {
      header('location:login.php');
}
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM chores ");
$query->execute();
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $query2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND()");
   $query2->execute();
      while ($row2 = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         $chore_id = $row['chore_id'];
         $user_id = $row2['ID'];
         $status = "Pending";
         $query3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM split_chores WHERE chore_id_fk = '".$chore_id."' AND user_id_fk = '".$user_id."' ");
         $query3->execute();
         if ($query3->rowCount()==0) {
            $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO split_chores(chore_id_fk,user_id_fk,status) 
            VALUES (:chore_id,:user_id,:status)");  
            $sql->bindParam(":chore_id",$chore_id); 
            $sql->bindParam(":user_id",$user_id);   
            $sql->bindParam(":status",$status );
            $sql->execute();    

         }
     }
}
echo "<script>alert('Chores have been splitted successfully');
window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL.

Comment: [ask] [mre] [help]

Answer (score 0):

This question probably belongs in StackOverflow actually as it's really a procedural programming problem, but I believe your issue is your code is basically saying *get all chores, then iterate over them, then for every chore, get all users, and iterate over them...*.  That's essentially what happens when your query uses `SELECT *` with no filters.

While you probably have no need to iterate so much, and again StackOverflow probably would recommend a better fix there, you can at least also solve your problem by reducing your result set for `$query2` to returning only 1 user by writing it the following way:

```
$query2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

The `LIMIT` clause reduces the result set to the number of records you specify (in my example above only 1 record) which will then only return 1 `user` and cause your iteration code to only loop once for `user`, (but still loop for every `chore`), to assign only 1 random `user` to a particular `chore`, instead of to all `chores`.